# Create an array with indeterminate length starting on 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have 50 (or less) arrays from database and I need to return them in one array.

I'm currently using

```
$results = DB::table('coinflip_history')->where('ct', Auth::user()->steamid)->orWhere('t', Auth::user()->steamid)->orderByRaw('round_id DESC')->limit(50)->get();
$results = json_decode($results, true);
$i=1;
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    if (!$value['winner']) $array[$i] = array('secret' => null, 'winning_string' => null, 'hash' => $value['hash'], 'timestamp' => $value['time']);
    else $array[$i] = array('secret' => $value['secret'], 'winning_string' => $value['percentage'], 'hash' => $value['hash'], 'timestamp' => $value['time']);
    $i++;
}

return array($array[1], $array[2], $array[3], $array[4], $array[5], $array[6], $array[7], $array[8], $array[9], $array[10], $array[11], $array[12], $array[13], $array[14], $array[15], $array[16], $array[17], $array[18], $array[19], $array[20], $array[21], $array[22], $array[23], $array[24], $array[25], $array[26], $array[27], $array[28], $array[29], $array[30], $array[31], $array[32], $array[33], $array[34], $array[35], $array[36], $array[37], $array[38], $array[39], $array[40], $array[41], $array[42], $array[43], $array[44], $array[45], $array[46], $array[47], $array[48], $array[49], $array[50]);
```

But if there are less than 50 arrays it's not working.

Is there any way to make it work automatically?

Comment: is 1 in $array[1] is a key of any array?

Comment: @splash58 I created the arrays using foreach with $i++; and then $array[$i]

Comment: @splash58 $array[$i] = array('secret' => $value['secret'], 'winning_string' => $value['percentage'], 'hash' => $value['hash'], 'timestamp' => $value['time']);

Comment: How are you generating the arrays initially - that code is where you should perhaps begin

Comment: that means  $array[$i] is sub-array of any big array? Why yuo want to rebuild that array?

Comment: aren't `$array` already an array of arrays from DB in this case? How exactly you want to reshape it if not?

Comment: @RamRaider I generate arrays with foreach from database.

Comment: `while() $arr[] = $row; return $arr;` ?

Comment: `return $array;` ?

Comment: kindly update the database retrieving fields.

Comment: @kovalenko-alex this would work but I don't need the $i displayed in the return array.

Comment: Why can't you `return $array ` directly?

Comment: @yivi as I said I don't need the $i displayed in the array.

Comment: Please add the code that you use to generate the arrays as it would seem the best place to generate the structure you want rather than afterwards?

Comment: @Nojus741 You don't change anything by your code - https://eval.in/934538

Comment: What `$i`? It doesn't make much sense, what you are doing is the same as returning the array itself, but skipping the first element (`0`) of the array.

Comment: @yivi $i is the number of the array and I don't need that number in the return array.

Comment: All array have indices. You can't generate an array without some sort of key. That's what an array *is*.

Comment: @yivi What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that array have indices, and are part of the array. What you call `$i`. Your code is kinda messed up, but that's life. Just `return $array;` and you are golden.

Comment: @yivi No, using this method it doesn't have a key that's why I used it, I don't  need that key.

Comment: The only thing you are accomplishing with your code is generating an array starting on 1, and assigning it to an array starting on 0. Check it [here](https://repl.it/repls/SplendidBlissfulPharaohhound).

Comment: The problem may lay in you are generating your first array (starting from1 instead of 0). Since what you are doing is functionally equivalent, I would have to guess you have some sort of problem down the line because of how you generated your first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All arrays have indices.

It's just [that kind of data data structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

**There is no way on PHP of generating an array without indices.** It wouldn't be an array.

The only thing you are accomplishing with your code is generating an array starting on 1, and then creating a new array starting on 0.

Since both things are functionally equivalent, I guess that the problem exist down the line when you return an 1-based array.

So if you would do:

```
$array = [];
$results = json_decode($results, true);

foreach($results as $key => $value){
    if(!$value['winner']) {
      $array[] = [
         'secret'         => null,
         'winning_string' => null,
         'hash'           => $value['hash'],
         'timestamp'      => $value['time']
      ];
    }
    else {
      $array[] = [
         'secret'         => $value['secret'],
         'winning_string' => $value['percentage'],
         'hash'           => $value['hash'],
         'timestamp'      => $value['time']
      ];
   }
}

return $array;
```

You'd get what you need. This is 100% the same than what you are doing up there, but with less steps, and that works for any number of values on the returned `$array`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was using array from 1 not from 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
// as simple as this
return $array;
```

Comment: Is not what I need. I need to output It without some kind of indices.

Comment: You don't need to **use** the key, but it always will be present. Take any array and pass it through `print_r($array)`. You'll see that it has indices. E.g. `$a = array('a','b','c'); print_r($a);`

Comment: return array('a','b','c'); and you won't see it.

Comment: @Nojus741, no you are wrong. Check the repl.it link that I left you up there.

Comment: @yivi Got it, thanks, the problem was that I was using array from 1 not from 0.

Comment: @Nojus741 maybe you can remove downvote from my answer since what I was answering is actually the same as jivi's answer, though not as wordy?